# Scheme lambda expression with zero arguments

Tags: lambda, scheme, arguments, zero

I thought this was a pretty trivial problem but I haven't seen any good example of this yet. I need to define a lambda expression that takes no arguments and will always return 0.

How would I define a lambda expression that doesn't take any arguments and returns something?

Comment: FYI a function with no arguments is often called a thunk.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What's wrong with (lambda () 0) ?

Comment: Not a thing, it just so happens that's the one thing I haven't tried.

Comment: You can also feel free to hand it an x input that it ignores, (lambda (x) 0) will do the same but is more confusing to look at.

Comment: @1_2_3_Reapeater With (x) it will require exactly one argument to work no matter if it is used or not. Much better to give it a rest parameter `(lambda rest 0)` that will literally ignore any number of arguments.

Answer (score 4):

Apart from the obvious answer of `(lambda () 0)`, many Scheme implementations provide a `const` function that takes a value and returns a function that returns that value no matter what arguments (or lack thereof) are given.

Answer (score 4):

```
(define (always n)
  (lambda ignore n))

> (define always-0 (always 0))
> (always-0 10)
0
> (always-0 'a 'b' 'c)
0
> (always-0)
0
```